# In Xcode, how to update a configuration `.xcconfig` file during the build phase?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS application with a `Local` configuration and associated scheme. This configuration is supposed to point to a service hosted on the developer's own machine (`localhost`). Since the app is sending requests to this service, it needs to reference the machine's IP address. This IP address can change overtime due to DHCP, and will be different for each developer anyway.

For these reasons, I'm trying to come up with a solution where the IP address would be set dynamically according to the machine's IP where Xcode is running.
Based on answers on StackOverflow, here's what I came up with.

First, my `Local.xcconfig` file defines this variable: `URL = http:/$()/$(LOCAL_DEV_IP_ADDRESS):8080/my-endpoint`

Then, I have added a `Run Script` as the last step of the build phases of my target with the following bash script:

```bash
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Local"* ]]; then
  filename="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/Local.xcconfig"
  search='$(LOCAL_DEV_IP_ADDRESS)'
  replace=`ipconfig getifaddr en0`

  sed -i '' "s/$search/$replace/g" $filename
  echo "\$(LOCAL_DEV_IP_ADDRESS) has been updated with the local machine's IP address (`ipconfig getifaddr en0`) in '$filename'"
fi
```

After a build, I can see that the `Local.xcconfig` file has been successfully updated in my build folder, but when I run it on a test device, the configuration isn't affected. When I make a request, I can see that the URL is set to `http://localhost:8080/my-endpoint` because the URL in my configuration is `http://:8080/my-endpoint`.

What am I doing wrong and why isn't my change affecting the app when it's run on a test device?